# upload and delete images php sql

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading, unlink

Ok,

I have built an insert image page (uploader.php) but I have 2 issues.

The code is:

```
<?php 

$target = "images/test/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

$title=$_POST['title']; 
$desc=$_POST['desc'];  
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

mysql_connect("dbhost", "dbuser", "dbpass") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error()) ;  
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('$title', '$desc', '$pic')") ; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?> 

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST"> 
Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br> 
Description: <input type="text" name = "desc"><br>  
Photo: <input type="file" name="photo"><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Add"> 
</form>
```

So the first issue is that the information is not being entered into the database - the table has 4 fields - id(int), title(varchar), desc(varchar) and photo(varchar). Is it because the id field is not being specified?? This is simply the auto incremented primary key for the table.

The second issue is that the image that is being loaded contains spaces in it - for example, when uploading "test image.jpg" - I would like to incorporate a str_replace to create "testimage.jpg". Do you know where I would insert this into the code?

Thanks again for any help,

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:)

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

That should do it :)

Comment: thanks - will get cracking and post the code up here once I have finished!